# How to backup/restore Rails db with Postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I do the following on my server:

```
 pg_dump -O -c register_production > register.sql
```

Then, after copying register.sql to my local environment, I try:

```
 psql register_development < register.sql
```

This appears to work, but when I try to launch the Rails site locally, I get this:

```
 PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "list_items" does not exist at character 28
```

How can I restore everything (including relations) from the server db to my local dev db?

Comment: Current references: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/backup.html | http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I use this command to save my database:

```
pg_dump -F c -v -U postgres -h localhost <database_name> -f /tmp/<filename>.psql
```

And this to restore it:

```
pg_restore -c -C -F c -v -U postgres /tmp/<filename>.psql
```

This dumps the database in Postgres' custom format (`-F c`) which is compressed by default and allows for reordering of its contents. `-C -c` will drop the database if it exists already and then recreate it, helpful in your case. And `-v` specifies verbose so you can see exactly what's happening when this goes on.

Comment: The problem here is that the pg_restore restores the database register_production, and I want the data restored to register_development on my local machine.

Comment: Hi! I have a problem with this command. I receive the following error: `pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation schema_migrations` . What could be a problem? Thanks!

Comment: fwiw if running postgres locally on a Rails development machine you generally will omit the -U postgres parameter

Comment: Sorry for hijacking. I've been trying to restore the database as per your command above. It looks like it's working as in I see a load of commands. But when I go in and have a look, none of the data has copied in. Any ideas?

Comment: I had the same issue as AI D, the pg_restore just dumps the the contents to STDOUT.  I fixed this by adding the -d <database_name> to the pg_restore command.

Comment: I'm unable to find this psql file in my tmp folder. where it will generate ?

Comment: how should i  give the  file  path when  i use windows machine . this is my  command   pg_dump -F p -U test -h localhost octopus_test -f C:\Users\Proobook\Desktop\Newfolder\test.sql

Comment: Use `rake db:drop` and `rake db:create` (without seed/migrate) instead of pg_dump `-c -C` as these options drop/create the given name **but restore into DB named in archive**.

Comment: @BeniCherniavsky-Paskin any idea on whether or not you'd first want to use the rake db:schema:load?

Comment: More than one person asking how to restore to a different database name.

Add a -d option if you want to change the database name like if your dumping a production and want to restore to a development, for example. 

`pg_restore -c -C -F c -v -U postgres -d <database_name>  /tmp/<filename>.psql`

Answer (score 1):

Does the register_development database *exist* before you run the `psql` command?  Because that form will not create it for you.

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE for more information.